# Babel loader unable to import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using babel loader with webpack for combining multiple React components. Although I've installed webpack and babel-loader along with its dependencies. I'm getting two errors:

```
ERROR in ./components/layout.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/Demo/Scorecard/SPA/React/components/layout.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
| 
| class Layout extends React.Component {
 @ ./build/import.js 15:14-49

ERROR in ./components/topic-list.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/Demo/Scorecard/SPA/React/components/topic-list.jsx Line 17: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     render: function () {
|         return (
|             <div>
|                 <div className="row topic-list">
|                     <SingleTopicBox 
 @ ./build/import.js 11:17-56
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

module.exports = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/import.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel',

            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ],
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    }
};
```

**import.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TopicsList from '../components/topic-list.jsx';
import Layout from '../components/layout.jsx';
```

**layout.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Layout extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <TopicsList />

            </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Try to remove `include` options from your webpack config file. *Include* folder should be the folder where webpack can find your loader in this case babel loader

Comment: As per @The answer removing `include` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ***include*** options from your *webpack.config.js* file. *Include* folder should be the folder where webpack can find your loader in this case babel loader

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your file structure but it might be the `include` part in `resolve` section of your webpack.config.js that results the problem.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

module.exports = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/import.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: THIS_SHOULD_BE_YOUR_SOURCE_FOLDER,
            loader: 'babel',

            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ],
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the React preset for Babel: `babel-preset-react`

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

And add it to your `babel-loader` presets.

Comment: Did you add it your presets  { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case and resolved it by removing the **exclude** part of the webpack rule (since the failing import was an import of an imported npm package that was in the **node_modules** directory).

So, applying to your example:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

module.exports = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/import.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel',

            // we want the loader to search in node_modules,
            // so we comment the line below
            // exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ],
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    }
};
```